# AngularJS: Not able to debug in chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools, angular1.6

I am trying to debug the following code in chrome while working with AngularJS 1.6. Its quite strange for me that it is not allowing me to put a debug point on line 11 as shown below :

[image]

Is there an issue with the code or I need any chrome plugin to do this?

Comment: Line 11 is unreachable. The JavaScript engine probably optimized it out of the compiled code. Images of code are not helpful. It makes it difficult to reproduce the problem.

Comment: put a console.log(" breakpoint "); just above line 13 and add break point to that point itself.